# wordpress theme customization does not reflect on new domain

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, demo

I've installed already built theme of "Shuffle Ground" "jevelin" and then installed demo content then created child theme and then started building pages through page builder , So not much coding required in child theme . But on deploying this site to another domain and changing links in "wp-options" from one domain to other domain i.e. `http://site1.com/demo/jevelin/` to `http://site2.com/` in all wp-options where previous name is found jevelin does not show updated content it shows default content of jevelin not the content i've updated in previous site , where am i mising on this ?

Comment: exported database and imported it into the new site right?

Comment: yes @LawrenceCherone

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it gives right content if i change site name to previous site , but does not gives right content on changing it to new site . Does it have get content from demo backup or something , I am not getting how this works exactly ?

Comment: `I've installed already built theme of "Shuffle Ground" "jevelin" and then installed demo content then created child theme` did you change the theme to the child theme.  Also when copying to the new domain, did you also import the database?  Copying the files is not enough.

Comment: I'm a little confused with what you mean by *site name*, what variable is that? Basically you need to do 3 things, copy the files, copy the database, spend 4 hours fixing absolute paths in database values because of wordpress bad design ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone in dbtable "wp-options" site_url , upload_url_path,home and all other url's because now site is on new domain so i've to replace previous links to new links that's why i've updated links in wp-options table

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I've updated all content tonew site and imported database to new site but still theiris some problem in updating links

Comment: @phpdevp did you hardcode the links, images, assets etc your having problems with, if so you will need to find and replace the old domain with the new one.

Comment: not images and assets but some custom url's which i remembered and replaced but doesn't do the thing . What is the actual concept of wordpress theme updation what prevention should i take first?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things that can happen here.

theme settings stored in database:
try updating the theme settings on the new site by just saving them again.
try moving your installation with tools made for stuff like that e.g. duplicator. Its easy to miss some changes on doing this manually like absolute server pathes.

theme settings stored in a file (yes some themes do that):
Make sure pathes inside a theme settings file (once you found it) are also changed.

Do you use a cache plugin? Or did you use one? Deactivate it and try to empty the cache folder.

Did you change the theme name/child theme name? This may cause issues too.

Did you change the htaccess? or forgot to copy it cause its a hidden file?

To move everything including content use duplicator. Best choice due to WPs bad code design

Edit:

to use duplicator - install it in the source site. activate it and create new package. Download installer and package provided.
On target site clean the folder (remoe all files/folders). insert installer and package. Call installer from URL and follow the guide

Comment: don't have cache plugin ,I 've Unyson,slider revolution ,envanto toolkit wordpress , in child theme i've given add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', function( $upload_url_path ) {
    return 'http://newsiteurl/wp-content/uploads';
});, din't change .htaccess but copied as it is dont know about duplicator , I'll redo all things  please suggest proper guidings @Pat_Morita

Comment: i added duplicator tutorial

Comment: ok can i try this first on localhost will this work on localhost ? @Pat_Morita

Comment: not able tobuild package after a long time running it says internal server error @Pat_Morita

Comment: did it give you any warnings after scan process?